# How to find the most frequent length of Heads in a Coin Toss?

Tags: java, coin-flipping

I need to find out which is the most frequent length for heads series. If there are more than one **most frequent** heads series lengths, print the longest. If there are no heads in the trial, print zero.

> Example :
>
> Input  : HTTHH
>
> Output : 2
>
> Input  : HTTHHHTTHHH

`EDIT : Sorry I forgot to include the Code.`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = br.readLine();
char[] c = str.toCharArray();

int currentLen = 0;
int frequentLen = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
    if (c[i] == 'H') 
    {
        currentLen++;
        if (currentLen > frequentLen)
        {
            frequentLen = currentLen;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentLen = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(frequentLen);
```

When I run this code, the output is different for some of the inputs.
For example: When I give `HHTTHHTTHHHTHHH` it shows `2` But according to the assignment it should display `3`.

Because if there are more than one **most frequent length** it should display the longest. Please help.

Comment: Have you produced any code?  Can you share it?  What does it output and what about your output does not meet your desired result?

Comment: "*I want to write a Java program...*" Great, what's stopping you?

Comment: Let your IDE indent your code, and you will understand. Then take the decision to always, always use curly braces after if/while/for, etc. The current, incorrect indentation of the code makes you think it does something other than what it really does.

Comment: I am sorry. I thought it would be too big here and that's why I deleted all those while posting. I always do include that in IDE.

Comment: include what? Are you telling us that the code in the IDE is not the same one as the one you posted? Never do that either. It's pointless to debug code that isn't even the real one.

Comment: Now you added the curly braces, but still didn't indent the code correctly.

Comment: You are just computing the maximum length, not the most frequent one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clear things up. The most frequent length of a sequence is the length that appears the most time. So somehow, you have to keep track of the number of sequences of each length that have already appeared. Here is the code to do that.

```
public static void freq() {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = br.readLine();

    // Count the number of times each sequence appeared. The array is indexed by the length of a sequence
    int[] counts = new int[str.length()];
    int current = 0;
    for (char value : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (value == 'H') {
            current++;
        } else if (current != 0){
            counts[current]++;
            current = 0;
        }
    }
    // If we end with 'H', increment the count
    if (current != 0) { counts[current]++; }

    // From the computed counts, find the one that appears the most often
    int mostFrequentLength = 0;
    int mostFrequentValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] >= mostFrequentValue) {
            mostFrequentValue = counts[i];
            mostFrequentLength = i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(mostFrequentLength);
}
```

Now, there are two loops in this code, but we can make it in one if we update the most frequent sequence in the first loop. Plus, you may want to find an alternative to creating an array of the same length as the string you are considering.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it now.

Comment: When I give one **H**, it shows Array index out of bounds exception as it increments `counts[1]` which exceeds the length of the array.

Comment: Well, then debug the code to take care of this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` is being associated with the second `if` instead of the first, and thus your `frequentLen` counter is being zeroed out at the wrong time. This is because you don't have curly braces in place to make the association clear to the compiler.  You should get into the habit of using curly braces for `if` statements all the time, even for one-line ones. They will prevent errors like this one.  Do not rely solely on indentation - it is not syntactically significant.  Also, as you are calculating the maximum length and not the most frequent length, it makes sense to change the variable name as well.

The corrected code is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String str = br.readLine();
char[] c = str.toCharArray();

int currentLen = 0;
int maxLen = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (c[i] == 'H') {
        currentLen++;
        if (currentLen > maxLen) {
            maxLen = currentLen;
        }
    }
    else {
        currentLen = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(maxLen);
```

Comment: You are computing the maximum length, not the most frequent one.

Comment: I usually target the specific question and leave it at that, but I'll incorporate your point.